# C - able to read an EVP encrypted file but when I store it in a char array, everything disappears

Tags: c, file, encryption

I have an EVP encrypted file which I want to send over a socket. However, I realised nothing was being sent because it seems like nothing was stored in the array that i read the file into, which I am sure there is something stored since I was able to decrypt after reading this file.

The code snippet below is the part that is boggling me.

```
    FILE *fp;
    long lSize;
    fp = fopen ( EVP_file , "rb" );
        fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END);
        int fsize = ftell(fp);
        fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_SET);
        unsigned char *indata = malloc(fsize);

     fread(indata,sizeof(char),fsize, fp);
     printf("%s\n", indata); // printing indata returns me nothing at all
     //then DECRYPTION
     //decrypting indata works! and i get what i want.
```

As commented, I get no output when I print indata. Is there something I am doing wrong here? I need to store it in this array so I can send it over a socket.

PS. When I use a plain text file, it works perfectly fine.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: The data is encrypted?  Then it's binary data and not a NUL-terminated string.  Also, `sizeof(char)` is `1` by definition.  And you need to actually check the return value from `fread()`.

Comment: Don't treat the data as a textual string. Print each byte value using `%u` or `%x` in a loop controlled by `fsize` to see what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's only text data (*ascii characters, perhaps utf-8, but not binary*) you need to `nul` terminate the buffer, add one extra byte to the `malloc()`ed size and then

```
indata[fsize] = '\0';
```

otherwhise you can't print it with `printf()`, instead you could do a hexadecimal dump to visualize the data, something like

```
for (size_t i = 0 ; i < fsize ; ++i)
{
    fprintf(stdout, "0x%02X ", (unsigned char) indata[i]);
    if ((i + 1) % 16 != 0)
        continue;
    fprintf(stdout, "\n");
}
```

whether it's useful or not depends on your interest in the data.

Also:

1. Check that `fopen()` did not fail, check the return value against `NULL` for tht.
2. Check that `malloc()` did not fail, also return value against `NULL`.

Comment: If it's encrypted data, the odds of there being no NUL characters in the stream are quite small.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem for this. Turns out, there was something in the char array all along and sending it through the socket works fine. The problem was that when I read it into another file on the receiving end, i used strlen(indata), which returned 0 because it wasn't really a String per se, and I was writing nothing into the file all along.